# Performing an update on objects from an array by using object own values

Tags: c#, mongodb, aggregation-framework

Having a collection sampled by next:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "6139b08ee5a3119445892f94"
    },
    "type": "bike",
    "specs": [
        {
            "name": "giant",
            "models": [
                {
                    "name": "v1",
                    "categories": [
                        {
                            "name": "v11",
                            "price": 0
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "v12",
                            "price": 0.1
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "v13",
                            "price": 0.1
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "v2",
                    "categories": [
                        {
                            "name": "v21",
                            "price": 1
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "v22",
                            "price": 0.1
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "sputnik",
            "models": [
                {
                    "name": "s1",
                    "categories": [
                        {
                            "name": "s11",
                            "price": 20
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "s12",
                            "price": 0.9
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "s13",
                            "price": 1.1
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "s2",
                    "categories": [
                        {
                            "name": "s31",
                            "price": 1
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "s32",
                            "price": 0.1
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

In order to edit `models` items by adding a new subdocument with next structure:

```
  "valid": {
           "isValid": true,
            "currentName": [value from name field]
        }
```

and remove field `name`

Almost achieved that by using Aggregations:

```
        var dineInOptionsDefinition =
                      BsonDocument.Parse("{ isValid: 5, currentName: '$specs.name'}");
        var addNewFieldsDefinition = new BsonDocument
                        {
                            { "$addFields", new BsonDocument
                                        {
                                            {
                                                "specs.models.valid", dineInOptionsDefinition
                                            }
                                        }
                            }
                        };

        var t1 = collection
            .Aggregate()
            .Match(filterDefinition)
                .AppendStage<BsonDocument>(addNewFieldsDefinition)
            .Merge(collection);
```

The problem I'm facing is the value for `currentName` - as result it's an array of concatenated `name` fields values. Any clue how to get the value from the current document field value?